# Pandas DataFrame: Substract one row to another taking into account index(name and date)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a python pandas Dataframe where I would like to see the changes between the latest 2 dates (when available) for a 3 indexed columns (phonetype, memory and brand).
The dataframe looks like this:

"""

[image]

"I would like to have the latest change of customers' holdings per brand, memory and phonetype.
So result would be (sorted by the latest change-when available):

"""

Which means, that that change of holdings for iphone1/32go/apple was one the 17/10/19, and was a decrease of .11 (-0.11), last change for iphone2/32g0/apple was on the 19/03/19, and a decrease of -.09 (-0.09), last change for iphone3/64g0 /apple was on the 05/12/16, and was a decrease of 0.12 (-0.12).
So basically substracting the 1st row by the second row, when the second row exist (meaning 2 records containing same phonetype/memory/brand with different dates). If the second row doesn't exit just show 1st row unchanged (first row [customer_holders]-0).

[image]

```
iphone4   32go        Apple        -0.50         01/11/2019
```

I don't know how to do this with pandas, without iterating through rows...
Any help would be much apeciated.
Thanks

Raw data are as bellow:

```
phonetype   memory  Brand   customers_holders   position_date
iphone1     32go    Apple   0.77                17/10/2019
iphone1     32go    Apple   0.88                10/10/2019
iphone1     32go    Apple   0.98                26/09/2019
iphone1     32go    Apple   1                   15/08/2019
iphone1     32go    Apple   0.9                 06/08/2019
iphone1     32go    Apple   0.8                 18/07/2019
iphone1     32go    Apple   0.8                 18/07/2019
iphone1     32go    Apple   0.74                20/06/2019
iphone1     32go    Apple   0.61                11/06/2019
iphone1     32go    Apple   0.5                 21/05/2019
iphone2     32go    Apple   0.5                 19/03/2019
iphone2     32go    Apple   0.59                16/01/2019
iphone2     32go    Apple   0.68                04/12/2018
iphone3     64go    Apple   0.5                 05/12/2016
iphone3     64go    Apple   0.62                11/11/2016
iphone3     64go    Apple   0.79                12/11/2018
iphone4     32go    Apple   0.50                01/11/2019
```

Comment: Are you sure the raw data is correct? Iphone3 doesn't have a `customer_holders` value of `-0.12` and what happened to Iphone2 in your result? Also what are `<0,5`?

Comment: right sorry about that, typoed. I have edited data, and consider <0.5 = 0.5, (happy to do just a replace to arrange the data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

**First**, change the date columns to type of `datetime` for to find the latest date.

```py
df['position_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['position_date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
print(df.head(10))
```

```
  phonetype memory  Brand  customers_holders position_date
0   iphone1   32go  Apple               0.77    2019-10-17
1   iphone1   32go  Apple               0.88    2019-10-10
2   iphone1   32go  Apple               0.98    2019-09-26
3   iphone1   32go  Apple               1.00    2019-08-15
4   iphone1   32go  Apple               0.90    2019-08-06
5   iphone1   32go  Apple               0.80    2019-07-18
6   iphone1   32go  Apple               0.80    2019-07-18
7   iphone1   32go  Apple               0.74    2019-06-20
8   iphone1   32go  Apple               0.61    2019-06-11
9   iphone1   32go  Apple               0.50    2019-05-21
```

and then
1. Sort in descending order for key columns and date columns.
2. Use `pd.groupby.diff` function, calculate the difference from the previous row by group.  [reference here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)!
3. I think you only need the difference between the latest date and the previous date, so use `drop_duplicates` to leave only the first row.
like this:

---

### Edit

Then, if diff is nan, you can add code to populate the value using `np.where`.
like this:

```py
key_col = ['phonetype','memory','Brand']
df = df.sort_values(by= key_col + ['position_date'], ascending=False)
df['diff'] = df.groupby(key_col)['customers_holders'].diff(periods=-1)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=key_col, keep='first')
# if diff is nan.   
df['diff'] = np.where(df['diff'].isnull(), -df['customers_holders'], df['diff']) 
print(df)
```

```
   phonetype memory  Brand  customers_holders position_date  diff
15   iphone3   64go  Apple               0.79    2018-11-12  0.29
10   iphone2   32go  Apple               0.50    2019-03-19 -0.09
0    iphone1   32go  Apple               0.77    2019-10-17 -0.11
```

To make it look like your result.

```py
df = df.drop('customers_holders', axis=1)\
.rename({'diff':'customers_holders'},axis=1)\
.sort_values(by='phonetype')\
.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

```
  phonetype memory  Brand position_date  customers_holders
0   iphone1   32go  Apple    2019-10-17              -0.11
1   iphone2   32go  Apple    2019-03-19              -0.09
2   iphone3   64go  Apple    2018-11-12               0.29
```

Comment: Tvm, I have a problem with the groupby which returns a 'diff' empty columns. Could this be because there is not always 2 different position date per phonetype/memory/brand? I have another row which is just: iphone4 32go Apple 0.50 2019-11-01 for instance, and i would like to see it as -0.50 in my result (0-0.50)